# Authentication by MAC address

Tags: views

I want to show a view only to users who use authenticate devices.
My plan is to add a custom user field users, populate it with the MAC address, and send the MAC address to the view. If the MAC address is valid, show the view content.

I don't know how to authenticate on the view side.

Is there any, module, custom code, or something else to check if the MAC address is valid?

Comment: Note that this approach **will not work** unless both devices are in the same actual network. That is, if your server is on the internet and your "clients" are users all over the world, then you need look at something else besides MAC addresses.

Comment: Also note that MAC addresses are very easily spoofed, basically meaning anyone on the LAN network could easily hack into someone elses account.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to override the `access callback` used for your view pages using an [`hook_menu_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) implementation (from a custom module) to use a custom one that will do the MAC address check.

Assuming the MAC address is provided as an HTTP header, this would look like.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function MODULE_menu_alter($items) {
  if (!isset($items['protected/view/path']['access arguments'])) {
    $items['protected/view/path']['access arguments'] = array($items['protected/view/path']['access callback']);
  }
  else {
    array_push($items['protected/view/path']['access arguments'], $items['protected/view/path']['access callback']);
  }
  $items['protected/view/path']['access callback'] = 'MODULE_menu_access';
}


/**
 * Return whether or not the request contains an authorized MAC address header. 
 */
function MODULE_menu_access() {
  $mac_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_MAC_ADDRESS'];

  // Validate the MAC address.
  if (!MODULE_mac_is_authorized($mac_address)) {
    return false;
  }

  // Return the result of the original access callback
  $args = func_get_args();
  $access_callback = array_pop($args);
  return call_user_func_array($access_callback, $args);
}
```